# Select top 5 MySQL after division of two rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a rating system that takes the rating of 1-5 then increments the number of votes and adds to a total number of rating. This is problematic for my top 5 leaderboard which currently provides Xml through a php web service from the MySQL database with this query:

```
FROM ratings ORDER BY totalRating DESC LIMIT 5
```

Now obviously this isn't going to work.

Is there a way to do the division of totalRating by noRating and THEN return order by?

I'm trying to keep this to the database level. Hopefully it's possible.

Edit:

So let's say my table ratings has two records:

```
Name | cRating | tRating //current number of ratings and total
Tv1  |    2    |    10  
Tv2  |    3    |    9
```

I need to do tRating / cRating then sort them into the top 5 shows

Desired result is to return the top 5 averagely rated results (sorry for the terrible formatting I'm on my phone)

Comment: I don't follow your logic.  Can you add sample data and desired results to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an arithmetic expression in the `order by`.  So this might do what you want:

```
order by tRating / nullif(cRating, 0) desc
```

Comment: This is and isn't working, it returns the correct top 5.. but the number returned is the rating count (cRating). e.g. Tv1 returns 2 rather than 10/2 = 5

Comment: @user3318955 . . . Then you need to change the `select ` as well as the `order by`.